# Ampersand '&' asking for subs value when & is used as a value in table

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

NOTE: i am new to sql.

****create table Employee_Details
(
Emp_id int,
First_name varchar(20),
Department_id varchar2(10),
Email_id varchar2(30),
Salary number,
Hire_Date date
);***

***insert into Employee_Details values(&empid,'&first_name','&deptid','&emailid',&salary,'&date');***

***select *from Employee_Details;****

***[101 Abigail 10_Prod Abigail_Abraham@priory.com  99446   24-JUN-97]*

*[102   Alexandra   10_Prod Alexandra_Allan@priory.com  35106   25-JUN-95]

*[106   Amy 20_R&D  Amy_Avery@priory.com    46237   29-JUN-95] ~some of the values.

---

**Q.  Write a Query to display all the employee details from  Employee_Details whose Department_id is not equal 20_R&D.**

MY ans-
***select *from Employee_Details where Department_id not in ('20_R&D');***

POP UP-Enter substitution value for D.

select *from Employee_Details where Department_id not in ('20_R&D');

wanted to output details not consisting '20_R&D'.

***desired output***

101 Abigail 10_Prod Abigail_Abraham@priory.com  99446   24-JUN-97

102 Alexandra   10_Prod Alexandra_Allan@priory.com  35106   25-JUN-95.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is

```
select *from Employee_Details where Department_id not in ('20_R&D');
```

Ampersand is recognized as a substitution variable character. If you want to "skip" it, you'll have to *undefine* it. How? Execute

```
set define off
```

and then try again.